# “member for” is a negative number on Data.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, data-explorer, timestamps

I've recently joined [Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), and seen this:

[image: member for: -56 second]

-55, -54, and counting… it reached 0, but then it started over from -59!
It seems [I'm not alone with this problem](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/member-for-is-a-negative-number-on-data-se)

Comment: can not find this in the code any more, I think we fixed it ... ping me if it is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a quick look, I suspect that this due to the fact that the user creation time is [specified as `DateTime.UtcNow`](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Models/User.cs#69), but the offset on that page is [calculated using `DateTime.Now`](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Views/User/Show.aspx#54). Since the data.SE server is [hosted in Oregon](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/stack-exchanges-architecture-in-bullet-points/), there's a several-hour period during which the registration time is ahead of the server's current time. This causes problems with the [`TimeTaken()` method](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/ExtensionMethods.cs#431), which expects the interval to always be positive.

Since the `TimeTaken()` method only checks to see if days, hours, and minutes are positive when choosing whether or not to display them, you'll see a fluctuating negative seconds value until the server time has passed the UTC time that your account was created at.

Presumably changing the view offset to `DateTime.UtcNow` would correct things, though I'm unable to verify at the moment that this is actually the problem. Once I'm able, I'll test to see if this is the case, and if so I'll try and get a patch ready.

Answer (score 5):

I did an independent analysis and came to the same conclusion as Tim did.

The problem is the combination of:

1. When a new user account is created, the creation date is recorded in UTC time, and
2. The user account page displays the time difference between the creation date and the current time, the latter of which was incorrectly using the server's *local* time, instead of the UTC time

So in fact, even if a given user currently has a positive number displayed in the `member for` field, it's still incorrect. This change will also fix that problem.

I've [patched this up](http://code.google.com/r/jseigelis-test/source/detail?r=ff4f1373b92639b05d7cbb1cccd902433aeda184) and notified @waffles.

Comment: Ah, I knew there was something I forgot to do when I got home. Good stuff!

Comment: This should be live now (can't really tell until someone registers a new account).

Comment: Still broken for me.

Comment: @Ple: waffles sent me a reply e-mail, so I assumed incorrectly, I guess. The change *is* checked into the trunk of the project, so I'm not sure what happened.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is probably an issue of time synchronization across different servers.