# SEDE seems convinced I will be a user in the future

Tags: bug, data-explorer, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“member for” is a negative number on Data.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76659/member-for-is-a-negative-number-on-data-se)

I just had to re-register on Data Explorer, and now it thinks [I will be a user](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/5373) in the future.  Only 33 seconds though.
[image: Profile with -33 seconds]