# I have been a member for how long?

Tags: bug, data-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“member for” is a negative number on Data.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76659/member-for-is-a-negative-number-on-data-se)

Apparently I have been a member for -52 seconds. I have refreshed the page a few times and although it cycles, it has so far remained negative, and with an absolute value of less than a minute.

[image]

Comment: 306 reputation points in -52 seconds.  That's got to be a record.

Comment: @David: Nah, different sites. They don't have rep on data explorer.

Comment: Getting a little bit ahead of yourself, aren't you? By about a minute...

Comment: I foresee ritual mockings for @Waffles in the near future...

Comment: Hmmm, [the tooltip](http://data.stackexchange.com/users/5749) says `4/25/2011 12:15:16 PM` while it's about `13:59 UTC` now.

Comment: Ah, I just witnessed a nice countdown to -3, -2, -1, 0, -59, -58, ...

Comment: I must be stuck in some sort of time loop ...

Comment: @Grace Note: I didn't see that one. That question appears to cover two different issues, I agree that this is a duplicate of the first half of that question, but only the second (unrelated) half appears to have been addressed.

Comment: I'm not exactly fond of it having only properly addressed the second issue, but the [other options](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80007/sede-seems-convinced-i-will-be-a-user-in-the-future) [for duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78873/bug-in-data-stackexchange-com-user-profile-page) are closed as a duplicate of it. Because whether or not the second part was addressed, the first is still a valid and still open bug report of the very same issue. In fact, the second issue is completely unrelated and has to do with chat.

Comment: Not too helpful, unless someone sees any relationship: at "member for" -24 seconds (tooltip: `4/25/2011 12:15:16 PM`), the "seen" said 21 seconds ago, with tooltip `2011-04-25 15:23:30Z`. So, can I assume the server time was about 15:23:09Z at that time? Still then: no cigar!